# getchar returns a different character

Tags: c, getchar

I'm trying to make a program I already made more organized by using functions. the purpose of it is processing a menu with several options for calculating different values. This code is for processing the Main menu, and the error I'm getting is that every character I type comes out as invalid (activates the default case in the switch) even if it is 1, 2 or 3, which are the possible options. What am I doing wrong?

```
void process_main_menu(){
int c;
print_main_menu();
int option=getchar();
while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF);
switch(option){
        case 1:
            program_state=ST_MENU_BASS;
            break;
        case 2:
            program_state=ST_MENU_TREBLE;
            break;
        case 3:
            program_state=ST_EXIT_PROGRAM;
            break;  
        default: 
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", MSG_INVALID_NUMBER);
            program_state=ST_MAIN_MENU;     
    }
}
```

I'm updating the code as I see it wasn't complete enough. I'm actually using macros for this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define OPT_MENU_BASS 1
#define OPT_MENU_TREBLE 2
#define OPT_EXIT_PROGRAM 3


typedef enum {
ST_MAIN_MENU,
ST_MENU_BASS,
ST_MENU_TREBLE,
ST_EXIT_PROGRAM,
ST_MENU_TREBLE_FREQ,
ST_MENU_TREBLE_GAIN,
ST_MENU_TREBLE_FREQ_FREQ_TREBLE,
ST_MENU_TREBLE_FREQ_RESISTOR_3,
ST_MENU_TREBLE_FREQ_CAPACITOR_3,
ST_MENU_TREBLE_GAIN_RES5,
ST_MENU_BASS_FREQ,
ST_MENU_BASS_GAIN, 
ST_MENU_BASS_FREQ_FREQ_BASS,
ST_MENU_BASS_FREQ_RESISTOR_2,
ST_MENU_BASS_FREQ_CAPACITOR_1,
ST_MENU_BASS_GAIN_RESISTOR_1,
} state_t;
state_t program_state;

void process_main_menu(){
int c;
print_main_menu();
char option=getchar();
while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF);
switch(option){
    case OPT_MENU_BASS:
        program_state=ST_MENU_BASS;
        break;
    case OPT_MENU_TREBLE:
        program_state=ST_MENU_TREBLE;
        break;
    case OPT_EXIT_PROGRAM:
        program_state=ST_EXIT_PROGRAM;
        break;  
    default: 
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", MSG_INVALID_NUMBER);
        program_state=ST_MAIN_MENU;     
}
}
```

Comment: The most basic debugging technique when something goes wrong like this is 'print the value the program actually read'.  Include `fprintf(stderr, "Got %d ('%c')\n", option, option);` in the `default` clause and you'd see the information that you typed `49 ('1')` which would strongly hint at why you have a problem.  It takes, perhaps, a bit more experience to know to print both the numeric and character versions of the value in `option`, but it becomes automatic over time.

Comment: Thank you for your completed post. You still ***cannot*** use `case OPT_MENU_BASS:` unless you do `case (OPT_MENU_BASS + '0'):`  because `OPT_MENU_BASS` is equal to decimal `1` ***not*** character `'1'` (which is actually decimal `49`) or you can do `switch(option - '0')` to make `option` a *decimal* instead of a *character*. Look carefully at e.g. [**ASCII Table.com**](http://www.asciitable.com/). Alternatively you could `#define OPT_MENU_BASS '1'`, but the redefinition of  `OPT_MENU_BASS` would likely cause issues elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but all of those options still give me the same error. I'll figure it out somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading in a character such as , which is stored as its ASCII code, not a numerical value.

You need to change your cases to look for the character `'1'`, not the number `1`.

```
    case '1':
        program_state=ST_MENU_BASS;
        break;
    case '2':
        program_state=ST_MENU_TREBLE;
        break;
    case '3':
        program_state=ST_EXIT_PROGRAM;
        break;
```

EDIT:

Given the macros you're using, you need to modify the macros to represent the characters `'1'`, `'2'` or `'3'` instead of the numbers `1`, `2` or `3`.

```
#define OPT_MENU_BASS '1'
#define OPT_MENU_TREBLE '2'
#define OPT_EXIT_PROGRAM '3'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Your solution works, but only for 2 and 3; if i type 1 it returns 2 messages of invalid numbers. Also, originally (and how it was supposed to be) replacing the numbers i had macros, like OPT_MENU_BASS assigned to values 1, 2 and 3, how could i do it using that?

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, all we can do is guess that you properly declare the global `program_state` and have properly `defined` the macros `ST_MENU_BASS`, `ST_MENU_TREBLE`, `ST_EXIT_PROGRAM`. We're good, but we cannot see your display from here...

Comment: @Andibadia See my edit.  You need to change the macros to use character constants, not numerical constants.

Comment: Yes, that worked! At first it didn't but I had a stupid error in my code that made me think that it didn't work. Thank you very much

Comment: @Andibadia Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.